# Opencv Cascade traning parameters clarification python on ubuntu server

Tags: python, opencv, cascade, ubuntu-server

For a week that i'm working with the **traincascade**, But still not clear to me what is the best way to do the training.
In some places I saw that `numPos` need to be 0.9*positive_samples or `numNeg` need to be twice bigger then the positive.
Not sure about all the formulas I saw around.
Last Q I saw is this one: http://answers.opencv.org/question/62437/traincascade-parameters-numpos-and-numneg/

The answer here isn't clear cause they told about who is bigger, but not in numbers.
Like "Negative need to be twice bigger then pos" Or Pos is 0.9*Samples etc..

How  `minHitRate` and `maxFalseAlarmRate`   have influence about the num parameters ?

*I'm runing the training on Ubuntu Server 18.04*

Comment: numPos must be smaller than tbe actual number of your available positive samples, because if your minHitRate is less than 1, you will lose samples on each stage (up to (1-minHitRate) which is about 0.1 of the total number for 20 stages and minHitRate 0.999), but you can't be sure that you won't lose additional yetvunused samples, because you don't know whether they share the features..

Comment: about negative samples: You can't know the optimal number, because you don't know what kind of features will be used and what kind of features are present in the samples. You typically don't even know the actually available number of sampley (subimages of your dataset) and even if you knew, you don't know the acceptance ratio of your training in advance  In general: The more negative samples, the better, if you have enough images ;)

Comment: Thank you very much @Micka, I understand the best is to put numPos = 0.9 * (Number of samples)

Comment: this will work in many cases, but could be too low for optmal results or too high to finishe the training, depending on your actual samples (since some of yet unused samples might be lost in earlier stages too). This can't be foreseen and so 0.9*numPos is a good value to begin with, which should work for most projects. If you finished training and want to improve the classifier without collecting new samples, you could try to increase the factor, if you want to spend the time and processing power ;) afaik, the optimal parameter values can't be known in advance.